# Django: Retrieving the private key of selected dropdown option in Ajax call

Tags: javascript, django

I have two models like this:

```
class ScenarioMarket(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
    description = models.TextField(default="")
    b = models.IntegerField(default=100)
    cost_function = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    open = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title[:50]

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('market_detail', args=[str(self.id)])

class Scenario(models.Model):
    description = models.TextField(default="")
    current_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
    share = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    market = models.ForeignKey(
        ScenarioMarket, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='scenarios', 
        default=None)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.description)
```

In my template, I have a dropdown menu that loops over (the descriptions of) all the scenarios available on the scenario market in question, with each option taking the `pk` of the relevant scenario as its value:

```
<form action="" method="GET" id="scenario-dropdown">
{% csrf_token %}
    <select>
        {% for description in scenariomarket.scenarios.all %}
        <option value="{{ description.id }}">
            {{ description }}
        </option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
</form>
```

What I then want to do is pick up the `pk` of the selected option in the dropdown menu in an Ajax call. I thought I would be able to it this way:

```
var scenario_id = document.getElementById("scenario-dropwdown").value
```

But looking in the console, I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null`, so clearly it's not working - likely with respect to the `<form>`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The select has no id, and the form has an id with a hyphen `-`, not an underscore. You als made a typo (it is `scenario-dropdown`). Note that this will give you the *form*, not the `<select>` input however.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem ah, of course! Fixing the typo and adding an `id` to the `<select>` did the trick. Thanks for your quick response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically made two mistakes here:

1. you should add the `id=...""` to the `<select>` tag *not* the `<form>` tag; and
2. you made a typo in the `id`: it should be `scenario_dropdown`, *not* `scenario-dropwdown`.

You can fix the template to:

```
<form action="" method="GET">
{% csrf_token %}
    <select id="scenario-dropdown">
        {% for description in scenariomarket.scenarios.all %}
        <option value="{{ description.id }}">
            {{ description }}
        </option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
</form>
```

and query in the JavaScript with:

```
var scenario_id = document.getElementById("scenario_dropdown").value
```